# Generalization of: The dimension of a projective $\mathbb{F}$-variety equals the smallest codimension of a disjoint linear subspace

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an algebraically closed field. Consider the following definition of the dimension of a (quasi)projective $\mathbb{F}$-variety, given in Harris *Algebraic Geometry: A First Course*:

[image]

It seems nonstandard to take this as the *definition* of a variety, so I will think of this as a theorem that should be proven from a more conventional definition of dimension, e.g. the [Krull dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension).

My question is this: Does Definition 11.2 generalize to structures other than a variety over an algebraically closed field? For example, what if $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$? Or $X$ is a manifold embedded in projective space? In these cases, does the dimension of $X$ still agree with the smallest codimension of a disjoint linear subspace?

Note that Definition 11.2 holds when the ``irreducible" assumption is dropped, so this small generalization does hold.

Comment: When you say "variety", what do you mean? The answer is probably "yes, it generalizes" if you set it up the right way and "no, not quite" if you don't.

Comment: @KReiser I mean a variety in the classical sense: the common zero-locus of a set of polynomials.

Comment: @KReiser I guess what I'm looking for then is a reference request. Is there a reference to such a result when $X$ is, for example, a manifold embedded in projective space?

Comment: Such a statement is easily seen to be false: draw a small circle in $\Bbb RP^2$ that misses some line, for instance. Depending on your definitions for varieties over $\Bbb R$, this could also be a counterexample for that case too.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks, that's a nice example. In my particular case, I'm trying to find the maximum dimension of a linear subspace of $n \times n$ matrices disjoint from the real $n^2$ dimensional Lie group $U(n,\mathbb{C})$. Based on your example, this seems more difficult than I expected.

Comment: [XY problems](http://xyproblem.info/) are particularly poorly suited for MO/MSE. Please consider providing context about your underlying problem to avoid this sort of issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112722/discussion-between-doremifasolatido-and-kreiser).